# Guage js text rotation issue not rotating text by changing the guage.js file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is anyone did changes in the Canvas guage.js file for rotating text to some degrees. Please help me to find the text to render on it. I'm attaching the URL of js which is used to render a guage in project.

[guage.js](http://github.com/bernii/guage.js)

Thank you

Comment: your github link is showing 404. Please check and add more code to help you further

Comment: the link is https://github.com/bernii/gauge.js

Comment: can you elaborate your post and add more code here to help you. as it will be too broad

Comment: yes ,I have used the canvas js (guage.js ) and i have to rotate the label on that guage which is be drawn on canvas

Comment: http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/  this t

Comment: the above provided link is the demo from which i have used it and want to change to provide the text on the gradient color that is also possible with the sane js but to rotate that text i need some help